# azure devops notification | if I have 10 releases is will send 10 emails?

Tags: azure-devops

[image]

1. can I add more then 1 email?
2. if I have 10 releases is will send 10 emails?, I want to send 1 email with all the releases names are created and deployed from specific build.

Answer (score 0):

The first point is achievable. Instead of choosing "Custom email address", you could add target users into a team, and choose "Team preference" or "Members of xxx Team".

[image]

The Second point is not supported by build-in feature. Every time a notification matches your setting, it will send an email. Refer to this offical doc: [email notification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/notifications/manage-your-personal-notifications?view=azure-devops&tabs=new-account-enabled)

**Update1**

If you would like to add 3 email address, you could separate them by ","

[image]

Comment: but I need 3 emails ... I dont want to do as you suggested

Comment: I have updated my answer, try separate 3 email address with comma: "1@a.com, 2@b.com, 3@c.com"

Comment: Hi @vfdsabvdasvd , I would like to check if separate 3 email address with comma could add multiple email accounts.

Comment: is send 3 emails not 1 .. is very spam